# Replace text between first bracket and . without removing the bracket and

Tags: r, regex, brackets

I would like to replace the 70 in between the brackets with a specific string lets say '80'.

from filter[70.00-100.00]  --> filter[80.00-100.00]

However when using the following code:

```
str_replace('filter [70.00-140.00]'," *\\[.*?\\. *",'80')
```

The output is:

```
filter8000-140.00]
```

Is there any way to replace the string between the \ and . (in this case 70) without removing the \ and .   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace any one or more digits after `[` use

```r
library(stringr)
str_replace('filter [70.00-140.00]','(?<=\\[)\\d+', '80')
sub('\\[\\d+', '[80', 'filter [70.00-140.00]')
sub('(?<=\\[)\\d+', '80', 'filter [70.00-140.00]', perl=TRUE)
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/ZSx4qX). The `(?<=\[)\d+` matches a location immediately preceded with `[` and then one or more digits. `\[\d+` matches `[` and one or more digits, so `[` must be restored and thus is added into the replacement pattern.

To replace exactly `70`, you can use

```r
library(stringr)
str_replace('filter [70.00-140.00]',"(\\[[^\\]\\[]*)70",'\\180')
# => [1] "filter [80.00-140.00]"

sub('(\\[[^][]*)70','\\180', 'filter [70.00-140.00]')
# => [1] "filter [80.00-140.00]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cK8znm/1). *Details*:

- `(\[[^\]\[]*)` - Group 1: `[`, then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `70` - a `70` string.

In the replacement, `\1` inserts Group 1 value.

Another solution could be replacing all occurrences of `70` strings inside square brackets that end with a word boundary and are not preceeded with a digit or digit+`.` (that is, to only match `70` as a whole integer part of a number) with

```r
str_replace_all(
  'filter [70.00-140.00]',
  '\\[[^\\]\\[]*]',
  function(x) gsub('(?<!\\d|\\d\\.)70\\b', '80', x, perl=TRUE))
# => [1] "filter [80.00-140.00]"
```

Here, `\[[^\]\[]*]` matches strings between two square brackets having no other square brackets in between and the `gsub('(?<!\\d|\\d\\.)70\\b', '80', x, perl=TRUE)` is run on the these matched substrings only. The `(?<!\d|\d\.)70\b` matches any `70` that is not preceded with digit or digit + `.` and is not followed by another word char (letter, digit or `_`, or connector punctuation, since ICU regexps are Unicode aware by default).

Comment: Thank you for your response! 
Would it also be possible without defining the 70? I am trying to replace all values between the [ and . in a column with a string from another column.
str_replace(hdr$filterString[1]," *\\[*?\\. *",'a')

Comment: @StuMet See my update.

Comment: yes sorry I should have defined the initial question differently. However the code you suggested:
str_replace('filter [70.00-140.00]',"(?<=\\[)\\d+", "80") 
Does exactly what i wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It will replace all digits between the [ and the . :

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\[)(\d*)(?=\.)/', '80', 'filter [70.00-140.00]');
```